# Any advantages of using ISO vs UTC time string formats in log files?

Tags: logging, server, analytics

What are some advantages or disadvantages of using ISO vs UTC date time string formats for logging? I am not asking for debate but information on best practices as it relates to several popular enterprise log readers and analyzers. For example, does Splunk or CloudWatch have a preference? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

For **Javascript**, I notice new Date() can accept either ISO or UTC string without issues, so no additional formatting is required.

For **Python**, 2.7 you need to provide the custom string format, so it works but a little tedious. In version 3.7 I see a new method called datetime.fromisoformat() but it will fail if there is a "Z" on the end.

`x = datetime.fromisoformat("2019-10-10T20:36:53.850Z") #fails`

`x = datetime.fromisoformat("2019-10-10T20:36:53.850") #works`

To me this somewhat implies the industry is leaning towards supporting ISO string format a little better.

I have experienced that posting in local time is problematic unless you also attach the time zone:

`Thu Oct 10 2019 16:36:53 GMT-0400`

I really have no idea about industry leading log readers.